# Slow USB transfer

Tags: kernel, usb

The transfer of files to a usb device has been very slow. On dslreports.com, a guy has found its cause. The problem occurs when you plug a USB 1.1 device at the same USB HUB where you are using the USB 2.0 device then it defaults to the lowest. Is there a solution for it? A solution where I can use both device at the same time without get slow transfer rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this is what's causing the problem? That shouldn't be happening... I have had USB 2 devices plugged in at the same time as USB 1.1 devices and there was no drop in transfer speed.

I'm guessing that either something else is using all of the bus bandwidth or your USB host controller is malfunctioning. Try plugging in different devices and seeing what happens. Do you get full speed from the USB 2 device when it is the only thing plugged in? What about the USB 1.1 device?

Comment: I've checked and my device is a usb 2.0 and not a 1.1 as I believed. I've tried again using both together ant it's just fine. :-s I don't know what had happened, as I've tried what the guy said and it worked I believed it was the problem....About the device, it is the cable of my old camera P150. Thinking about it, it's really weird that I've gotten slow transfer even when there was no camera plugged. Weirder is the fact that I've gotten full speed after remove it. Anyway, thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may read as snarky, but it certainly doesn't intend to.  Briefly, if you have multiple usb host ports, use them instead of a powered hub.

Comment: I'm not using a extern powered hub. By hub I meant the set of usb ports on the motherboard wich are recognized as a hub.
Tks

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is because your hard disk is too fragmented...